# Уставновка сертификата в Windows 7

Tags: windows, wsus

Клиентские Windows 7 получают обновления с локального **WSUS**, рядом с которым стоит ещё и **[LUP](http://localupdatepubl.sourceforge.net/)** для автоматической установки и обновления различного стороннего ПО.

Если настройка на WSUS выполняется через reg-файл

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]@="""WUServer"="http://wupdate""WUStatusServer"="http://wupdate""AcceptTrustedPublisherCerts"=dword:00000001"ElevateNonAdmins"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]"UseWUServer"=dword:00000001"DetectionFrequencyEnabled"=dword:00000001"DetectionFrequency"=dword:00000001"EnableFeaturedSoftware"=dword:00000001"AutoInstallMinorUpdates"=dword:00000001"IncludeRecommendedUpdates"=dword:00000001"NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers"=dword:00000001

То что бы установить ПО через **WSUS** нужно на клиентские машины установить сертификат, которым **LUP** подписывает "обновления" (MSI инсталляторы ПО). Причем сертификат должен желательно ставить не пользователю, а на машину и сразу в две группы "*Доверенные издатели*" и "*Доверенные корневые центры сертификации*".
Прочел по этому поводу [справку на MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc766314(v=ws.10).aspx), но ответа на вопрос установки сертификата в нужные группы не нашел...

Если кто сталкивался, поделитесь опытом, как делали вы...

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой вариант решения:
Т.к. оснастку сертификаты возможно использовать и из консоли, посмотрите какими командами это сделать и, возможно Вам это подойдет. Останется только решить проблему с распределением данной команды на все Ваши машины.
Вот навскидку:
Как установить сертификат из командной строки?
[Установка сертификатов в автоматическом режиме](http://forum.oszone.net/thread-80064.html)
[Microsoft: Certmgr.exe (средство диспетчера сертификатов)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e78byta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Установка сертификата в Windows из командной строки](http://tikhonovan.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-windows-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE/)

Comment: Спасибо, надеюсь что это то что нужно.  Если удастся поднять AD под Ubuntu на основе Samba4, то распространение скрипта или батника по компам думаю решить через групповые политики.

Comment: хм. если нет развернутого AD, то возможно это не сработает.  Тогда можно попытаться использовать DameWare (она может выполнять пакетные задания - вот только не могу сейчас посмотреть части работы с сертами через RPC есть там что нибудь? - ) - по крайней мере он может в режиме удаленно-выполняемого приложения запустить что-либо.